# Ubuntu 12.10 running on VMWare Fusion 3.1.1

Tags: vmware-fusion

Here is a picture of the problem:
http://screencast.com/t/x0rpYrqa

For some reason, Ubuntu 12.10 32-bit in VMWare Fusion 3.1.1 is showing multiple small screens. I am not aware if Ubuntu 12.10 is or isn't supported with this version of VMWare, but if anyone could help that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

VMware Fusion 3.1.x is quiet old. The release notes says it only supports up to Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. I don't think 12.10 is well supported anyway, especially when you run Unity.

http://www.vmware.com/support/fusion3/doc/releasenotes_fusion_31.html

Try to ssh to your guest and install VMware tools in it. Also try to install a different DM/WM like xfce4, lxde, fluxbox/openbox or awesome and see if that works better.